# R_386_32 Relocations in shared library

Tags: gcc, linker, loader, relocation

Trying to understand how the relocation happens in the situation below
I have a shared library libbigshr.so which uses another shared library libfunlib.so. In the latter I have declared this global variable foo. To compile the former I had to do forward declaration as **`extern int foo`**.

**.rel.dyn at libbigshr.so**

```
Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name

000005a5  00000401 R_386_32          00000000   foo
000005ab  00000401 R_386_32          00000000   foo
000005c7  00000401 R_386_32          00000000   foo
```

**.rel.dyn at libfunlib.so**

```
000005a5  00000901 R_386_32          00002010   foo
```

In the libfunlib the translation offset is proper value (0x2010), therefore I don't have problem. But wanted to know the how the correct addresses were inserted in libbigshr. I can understand, that once a variable has been allocated the memory and its location is identified the same can be used everywhere else. But I am interested in the procedure of doing so.

Due to my ignorance my question may not have sufficient data to answer it - so please let me know and I will furnish more details.

Answer (score 1):

The correct address is generated by relocation processing at run time, by the dynamic linker.  For example, in glibc, `R_386_32` is processed in the i386 version of the `elf_machine_rel` function in the file `sysdeps/i386/dl-machine.h`.  The glibc wiki has an [overview of process startup](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/DynamicLoader).  For details, see the references in the [Linux Standard Base](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/elf-generic.html), particular those concerning the [System V Application Binary Interface](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/normativerefs.html#STD.ABIUPDATE).  For machine-specific information, H.J. Lu maintains a set of [x86 ABI documents](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI).

Comment: Agree. I calculated and verified that in gdb for libfunlib.so. But wanted to understand the same for the other library. Thanks and +1 for pointers. Need more help to understand the rest.